# Stratified Random Sample

Tags: python, random, large-data, sample, audit

I have a large population of vouchers.  I need to stratify the random sample according to dollar amounts.  There are four categories of dollar amounts with percentage of population to be 1%, 2%, 3%, 4%. $0-$500, $500-$2000, $2000-$5000, and greater than $5000.

In Python: How do I

1. Create code that can identify which category the voucher amount belongs
2. Return/print selected samples from each of those categories reflective of the required percentage of population.

I searched for "Stratified random sample" or something like that and have not found what would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

max_prize_money = 100000

percentages = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
dollars = [(0, 500), (500, 2000), (2000, 5000), (5000, max_prize_money)]

def get_category_from_voucher_amount(voucher_amount):
    for a, b in dollars:
        if a < voucher_amount <= b:
            return (a, b)

def sample(n):
    bounds = random.choices(
        population=dollars,
        weights=percentages,
        k=n
    )
    samples = []
    for a, b in bounds:
        amount = randint(a, b)
        samples.append(amount)
    return samples


print(get_category_from_voucher_amount(200))
print(sample(8))
```

prints

```
(0, 500)
[3554, 40121, 280, 992, 142, 60805, 218, 78723]
```